# Why does a LoadCursorA call give a build error?

Tags: windows, rust, windows-rs

Why does a LoadCursorA generate 'trait implementation' build errors when a LoadCursorW call does not when using the rust Crate for Windows?

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
use windows::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::LoadCursorA;
use windows::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::IDC_ARROW;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let _h_cursor = LoadCursorA(None, IDC_ARROW);
        //let _h_cursor = LoadCursorA(None, &IDC_ARROW);
    };
}
```

error[E0277]: the trait bound `PWSTR: IntoParam<'_, PSTR>` is not satisfied

Comment: Can you paste the compiler error also?

Comment: Because [`IDC_ARROW` is a `PWSTR`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/UI/WindowsAndMessaging/constant.IDC_ARROW.html) and so cannot be used with the `…A` functions, which require a `PSTR`.

Comment: Can the LoadCursorA call be modified to build and if so how? Thanks.

Comment: `IDC_*` constants are not really pointers but short integer constants disguised as pointers, so you should be safe doing `IDC_ARROW as PSTR`.

Comment: Trying IDC_ARROW as PSTR gives error[E0605] non-primitive cast: `PWSTR` as `PSTR`

Comment: `PSTR(IDC_ARROW.0 as _)` should work for the conversion.

Answer (score 3):

The reason `IDC_ARROW` doesn't work with `LoadCursorA` is because [it is a `PWSTR`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/UI/WindowsAndMessaging/constant.IDC_ARROW.html), so it can only work with `…W` functions. Functions in `…A` need a `PSTR` instead.

However `IDC_ARROW` is not really a `PWSTR` (ie. a "pointer to wide-character string"). It's just a small constant masquerading as a `PWSTR`, so we can convert it to a `PSTR` and pass that to `LoadCursorA`:

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
use windows::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::LoadCursorA;
use windows::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::IDC_ARROW;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let _h_cursor = LoadCursorA(None, PSTR(IDC_ARROW.0 as _));
    };
}
```

Of course another option is just to use `LoadCursorW` instead:

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
use windows::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::LoadCursorW;
use windows::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::IDC_ARROW;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let _h_cursor = LoadCursorW(None, IDC_ARROW);
    };
}
```